# PiCAN2 network is down

Tags: pi-3b+, communication

I am using RPi 3 model B+. I am trying to set up can communication using Pi CAN2 (From SKpang) with baud rate 500000.

But I am getting "write: Network is down" whenever I am sending "./cansend can0 401#01" in command window.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: did you connect at least a second device on the CAN bus that can acknowledge the sent messages?

Comment: Hi, CAN connection to Pi is tapped from already existing system. The system is working fine but I want to control it via RPi. I took CAN log, in which CAN frame sent from Pi board is not captured. Its saying "Network low"..!